# How to access Dictionary items sequentially in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Is it possible to access the items sequentially on the dictionary. I know that dictionary mainly intended for random access. When I am trying to access as key value pairs, my order changes to name, id, header,...etc

```
let inputDataSet = ["id":1, "name":"Thomas", "role":"Programming Geek", "header":"bla", "dept":"nloo", "address":"dsd", "pic":"asd"

for (key,value) in inputDataSet {
      print("current key:\(key) value:\(value as! String)")
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries have no order.

Comment: @rmaddy Is List available in Swift?

Comment: Review the section on collections in the Swift book.

Comment: @rmaddy i had traversed through below url but didnt found anything useful for me https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: What does "sequentially" mean to you? Give example of desired output.

Comment: Plan A - id followed by name followed by role
Plan B - role with its index followed by any other noseqential with its index and so forth

If Plan A is impossible then How can i get the index of a dictionary item that i have now

Comment: "Plan A - id followed by name followed by role" So fetch `inputDataSet["id"]` followed by `inputDataSet["name"]` followed by `inputDataSet["role"]`.

Comment: I need to traverse instead of accessing by key

Comment: "Traverse" is meaningless. Well, it's not meaningless, but you already know that it gives the key-value pairs in an unpredictable order.

Comment: @matt Yes matt, I got it. So My Plan A is failed so we have Plan B only now. In Plan B, Is it possible to get the index of the item that i get randonly in Dictionary?

Comment: I don't know what "the index of the item that i get randonly" means.

Comment: @matt For Eg. For the first iteration, if the system gives me the key="dept" and value="nloo" then is it possible to get the index as 4

Comment: There is no meaningful sense in which the "debt":"nloo" pair has index 4. Dictionary has no order. Gosh, isn't that what rmaddy said 25 minutes ago?

Comment: Is there a list datastructure in ios swift?

Comment: It's called Array.

Comment: Ok......If that's the case is it a good to make an Array<Dictionary<String,any>>

Comment: The use of `Any` really should be considered a bad code smell in Swift. Yes, it has its uses but it throws type safety to the wind and is counter to a lot of Swift design. Instead of using `[String, Any]` you should consider a real `struct`.

Comment: @ColGraff Thank u colgraff for the new info. I was unaware of the fact. U meant to say about the Generic Templating  right? for using Int, Float, String for a single type.

Comment: Thank u for your valuable contribution for solving this problem @ rmaddy @ matt @colgraff @ shial @ duncan

Comment: No, I did not mean that. I mean that if you know the keys and types of your data then you should have a `struct` which has properties like that instead of a grab bag of `Any`.

Comment: can u give an example plse? @ColGraff

Comment: `struct Foo { let id: Int; let name: String; /* and so on */ }`

Comment: I'm using a generic function func fnAbc(my_variable) which takes my_variable as an argument. So in my scenario i can't fix it that i will give this set of key-values all the time. But for future arch design of my next app.  I will try to reduce the use of Any @ColGraff

Comment: It sounds like you’re fighting a lot of Swift functionality by creating your own analogs of Swift objects through `Dictionary` and free functions. You might want to brush up on the rest of Swift and put it to use, it will save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: I'm completely new to the Swift Stack. Is the below url[1] good for studies?  Thank u @ColGraff

[1] - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: @ThomasEaso if you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs you can use a DictionaryLiteral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option for you here would be `KeyValuePairs`

> A lightweight collection of key-value pairs.

when you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t require the fast key lookup

```
let recordTimes: KeyValuePairs = ["Florence Griffith-Joyner": 10.49,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.76,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.79,
                                      "Marlies Gohr": 10.81]
print(recordTimes.first!)
// Prints "("Florence Griffith-Joyner", 10.49)"
```

Ref: [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs)

However, If you want to solve it different way I would recommend `Array`. To have a key, value in collection you can store it in `Tuple`. Let say array of tuples. Take a look on example below:

```
let inputDataSet: [(String, Any)] = [("id",1), ("name","Thomas"), ("role","Programming Geek"), ("header","bla"), ("dept","nloo"), ("address","dsd"), ("pic","asd")]

for (key, value) in inputDataSet {
    print("current key:\(key) value:\(value)")
}
```

Result of the sniper above is as presented below:

```
current key:id value:1
current key:name value:Thomas
current key:role value:Programming Geek
current key:header value:bla
current key:dept value:nloo
current key:address value:dsd
current key:pic value:asd
```

Thanks to this you have an order and key, value object.
Hope it helps!

Update:

Answer was updated to reflect changes.

[Renaming the DictionaryLiteral type to KeyValuePairs](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0214-DictionaryLiteral.md)

Comment: Thank u @Shial. This sounds Good. Lemme try in my Current Scenario

Comment: @ThomasEaso let me know if that did help you

Comment: Sorry for the delayed Response. I went to checkout whether this helps in my current scenario. Thank u Shilal for the right answer. Shilal feel free to UpVote the question also.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `DictionaryLiteral`

> A lightweight collection of key-value pairs. Use a DictionaryLiteral
>   instance when you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and
>   don’t require the fast key lookup that the Dictionary type provides.
>   Unlike key-value pairs in a true dictionary, neither the key nor the
>   value of a DictionaryLiteral instance must conform to the Hashable
>   protocol.

Note: `DictionaryLiteral` also allows duplicates keys

```
let inputDataSet: DictionaryLiteral<String, Any> = ["id": 1, "name":"Thomas", "role":"Programming Geek", "header":"bla", "dept":"nloo", "address":"dsd", "pic":"asd"]

for (key, value) in inputDataSet {
    print("current key:\(key) value:\(value)")
}
```

This will print

> current key:id value:1
>
> current key:name value:Thomas
>
> current key:role value:Programming Geek
>
> current key:header value:bla
>
> current key:dept value:nloo
>
> current key:address value:dsd
>
> current key:pic value:asd

edit/update:

**Swift 5 • Xcode 10.2**

The `DictionaryLiteral` type has been renamed to `KeyValuePairs`. [SE-0214](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0214-DictionaryLiteral.md)

```
let inputDataSet: KeyValuePairs<String, Any> = ["id": 1, "name":"Thomas", "role":"Programming Geek", "header":"bla", "dept":"nloo", "address":"dsd", "pic":"asd"]
```

Comment: That one is new to me. Thanks for enlightening me. (voted). I bet it has O(n) performance though...

Comment: Although `DictionaryLiteral` is kind of a pain to use since it doesn't support subscribing. `aDictLiteral.first(where: {$0.0 == "key"})` is awfully verbose. I guess the designers don't want anything with O(n) performance to use subscripting.

Comment: I prefer $0.key == "key"

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries in Swift and Objctive-C are unordered collections. They do not have any native order. If you want your data to be stored in a specific order, use an array of some other objects. (Structs, or even an array of dictionaries.)